# Cannot update apk on the device

Tags: android, apk

I have an app already installed on the phone. If I try to update it, it says "You can't install the app on your device". But if I uninstall and install it, it installs fine, it's only the case when i try to update it it fails.

I have checked the SHA256 for both certificates of the apk and they both are same. Package name is also same. I am not sure what is causing this issue.

Update:
This is installed directly onto the phone by downloading the apk to the phone and clicking on install. Both old and versions are installed in the same way.

I am trying to install the Release build.

Comment: The question needs more details. Is the installation / update performed over Google Play or from Android Studio? What build variants are you using? etc... Please specify.

Comment: One issue could be that there is not enough space for the app to update, since updates require twice as much space where an install will take only the APK size (or its extracted size). If package name and signatures are equal, it should update without any problems unless something external is going on. The installing app should open the default package manager which should handle everything.

Comment: Maybe try installing over adb and see the error code? It could help investigate the issue further.

Comment: @FurkanYurdakul Yes, thank you so much. Installing via adb showed the error. The problem was related to version code.

Comment: The app update must have the same or a bigger version code for it to install, yes. You can just stick to a bigger version since they'll only be accepted to Play Store that way.

Comment: Yes, thank you. We don't release via play store. That's why we missed it.